# MetaSynth 4 Pro

Tags: recommendations, sound-design, sound-effects, mix, effects

i need something similar to the MetaSynth , for PC daw, any recomendations??? i realy like MetaSynth, too bad that is not for pc

Answer (score 1):

Last month I searched like you something similar for PC.
Nothing compares 100 % to Metasynth.

The first thing I would try is  photosounder.
http://photosounder.com/

atmogen  http://www.sonorouscodes.net/
There`s a demoversion in english.
You can do many things with this demo version.
Great prg, but don`t know if the company still in business.

Audiopaint    free prg

coagala     free prg

Reinhard

Answer (score 1):

[Adobe Audition 3](http://www.adobe.com/products/audition/) does the sound-to-image-to-sound thing, and lets you do effects in the time-frequency plane using the lasso tool.